# How to edit array elements (array of objects) with angular formly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I would like to create a form with a dynamic number of similar sections. When I have this data structure for example:

```
var data = [
  {
    bla: 'blub',
    blabla: 'blubblub'
    someDate: '12/12/99'
  }, {
    bla: 'blub',
    blabla: 'blubblub'
    someDate: '12/12/99'
  }, {
    bla: 'blub',
    blabla: 'blubblub'
    someDate: '12/12/99'
  }
];
```

I would like to dynamically add and remove elements and add and remove the form fields for those accordingly. So when I would have 3 elements I would have three different form sections with an input for every object key and when I would have 2 elements there only would be 2 form sections.

Inside this form sections I would like to be able to use other formly fields as usual.

How would I achieve this using a custom formly field?

Comment: I would recommend that you handle this outside of angular-formly. Have your own code that does an `ng-repeat` on `data` and inside your `ng-repeat` have a custom directive component that uses `formly-form`.